# Как отсеять только англоязычные слова?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть список выражений типа

> Сделал дело - гуляй смело
>
> Business before pleasure
>
> 喜びの前のビジネス
>
> Correct - 喜びの前
>
> 23452345 345 234523
>
> Ваше имя - Armstormg?
>
> Are you sure?
>
> Are you 18 years old?

Надо с помощью preg_match проверку, которая позволит вывести только те, где отсутствуют не английский символы (кирилица, иероглифы, одни лишь цифры). Т.е. из текущего списка оставить

> Business before pleasure
>
> Are you sure?
>
> Are you 18 years old?

Набросал вот такой вариант

```
if(preg_match('/[g-z]|[a-f]{3,}/i',$start_array[$i]['titl'] ))
{
выводить строку
}
```

Но не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Само выражение будет примерно таким: `/^([\da-z -]*?[a-z]+[\da-z -]*?[?.!]*?)$/mi`

В PHP это будет выглядеть так:

```php
$rExp = "/^([\da-z -]*?[a-z]+[\da-z -]*?[?.!]*?)$/mi";
$sTxt = "Сделал дело - гуляй смело
1991 year - Business before pleasure
喜びの前のビジネス
Correct - 喜びの前
23452345 345 234523
Ваше имя - Armstormg?
I am 20
Are you sure?
Are you 18 years old?
50 не 20.
50 is not 20...";

foreach (explode("\n", $sTxt) as $str) {
    if (preg_match($rExp, $str)) echo "$str\n";
}
```

Аналогичное демо на JS:

```js
const rExp = /^[\da-z -]*?[a-z]+[\da-z -]*?[?.!]*?$/mi;
const sTxt = `Сделал дело - гуляй смело
1991 year - Business before pleasure
喜びの前のビジネス
Correct - 喜びの前
23452345 345 234523
Ваше имя - Armstormg?
I am 20
Are you sure?
Are you 18 years old?
50 не 20.
50 is not 20...`;

sTxt.split('\n').forEach((str) => {
  if (rExp.test(str)) document.write(`${str}<br>`);
});
```